# Using draggable, is position really changed after doing "over event" of droppable?

Tags: jquery

I have two div like this http://jsfiddle.net/bdhqu/
When drag the brown over to the green then the green got margin-left: 300px and display text "over" at bottom. The green moved to another place, ok, but its position seem doesn't move because  I still hold the mouse and drag to the old green's position then display "over over over". It will not happen if you drag to the new green's position.

Why and is there anyway to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Added an update to your demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/bdhqu/2/

All you need is to do is add option to draggable:

```
refreshPositions: true
```